# Valor devuelto por una orden simple (128+n)

Tags: linux, bash

Buenas noches a la comunidad stack.
Estoy estudiando el man bash, y en "gramática de shell" me surge una duda, que, en principio, no es estrictamente de programación, por lo que si se considera fuera de lugar (espero me digáis si es así), editaré para borrarla.

De acuerdo al man bash:

> El valor devuelto de una orden simple es su estado de salida,  ó  128+n  si  la  orden  ha terminado debido a la señal n.

Entiendo que las señales a que se refiere son las descritas en el man signal, como por ejemplo SIGKILL (9), que mata un proceso, o SIGILL (4), referida a una instrucción ilegal.
Sin embargo, bien leído el man signal,

> Linux  soporta  señales  en  tiempo  real  tal  como  está  definido  originalmente en las extensiones de tiempo real de POSIX.4  (ahora  incluidas  en  POSIX  1003.1-2001). Linux soporta  32  señales  en  tiempo real, numeradas del 32 (SIGRTMIN) al 63 (SIGRTMAX).  (Los programas deben hacer referencia siempre a las señales en tiempo real usando  la  notación SIGRTMIN+n,  puesto que el rango de números de señales en tiempo real varía entre sistemas Unix's.)

(Las señales del 1 al 31 serían las señales estandard).

¿Existe, entonces, la señal 128? ¿Qué significado tiene y dónde viene definida?

```
alfonso@foresthost:~/scripts$ uname -r && bash --version 4.16.0-686-pae GNU bash, versión 4.4.23(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Edito: 
Asumiendo que 128+n es una señal en tiempo real (igual es demasiado asumir por mi parte), ¿el valor devuelto por una orden simple, cuando la orden termina con la señal n, no debiera ser 32+n (SIGRTMIN+n)?

Lo dicho: muchas gracias, y si la pregunta excede el ámbito de stackoverflow hacédmelo saber, que retiro la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una señal es diferente a un estado de salida. Ahora, lo del número 128 creo que es (sin referencias) por 256 (de los estados de salida disponibles) entre 2. Que sería la shell donde se corre y una subshell de donde se emita la señal menor o igual a 128.

Por ejemplo.

```
$ export senial
$ for senial in {1..15}
for> do
for> bash -c 'bash -c "kill -$senial \$\$"; echo "$?"' 2> /dev/null
for> done
129
130
0
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
```

Y me muestra su **estado de salida** como el **estado de salida** 128 + la **señal**.

Si incluyes el rango {1..123} en el for, ves que el estado de salida es según la fórmula descrita, pero hasta la señal 32. Después, en el rango de [32-64], la salida es de 0, después, la salida es de error general, osea igual a 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus aclaraciones @mcr_es, más en estos días de fiestas, que mal se saca un rato para postear. Te voto: tu respuesta me ha aclarado lo suficiente como para, con un par de búsquedas en Google, haya, creo, despejado todas mis dudas.

Answer (score 2):

Acaso por redacción, @mrc_es, entendiste que no diferenciaba entre estado de salida y señal. 
Por si a alguien que llege aquí le ayuda: 
El **estado de salida** "determina el destino del resultado de un programa o proceso; por defecto es la pantalla y se muestra el resultado de un programa o proceso; por defecto es la pantalla y se muestra el resultado en la consola de la terminal, aunque puede redirigirse hacia un archivo". O a otros "lugares", añado, como el saco sin fondo /dev/null...
No he encontrado una definición mejor de **señal** que "una notificación o evento asincrónico que un proceso le envía a otro".
Sí que he podido leer que hay hasta 256 señales disponibles en GNU/Linux, y, de hecho, el apéndice E de la Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) (Códigos con significados especiales) manifiesta:

> exit codes 1 - 2, 126 - 165, and 255 [1] have special meanings, and should there fore be avoided for user-specified exit parameters. 
>   [...]
>   
>   There has been an attempt to systematize exit status numbers (see /usr/include/s ysexits.h), but this is intended for C and C++ programmers. A similar standard for scripting might be appropriate.
>  
>   [...] 
>   [1]Out of range exit values can result in unexpected exit codes.
>   An exit value greater than 255 returns an exit code modulo 256. For example, exit 3809 gives an  exit code of 225 (3809 % 256 = 225).

De nuevo desde mi más absoluta ignorancia, y sin una fuente que pueda citar, me atrevo a aventurar que, a nivel de kernel, cualquier señal es enviada como un solo bit, lo que permitiría un maximo de 256 señales (2 elevado a 8). Otra cosa es que exista un significado definido para cada una de ellas: el man signal es ilustrativo al respecto.
De nuevo gracias, @mrc_es.
Pd: me he atrevido a contestar mi propia pregunta, estando respaldada en poco más que mi propia lógica, porque en comentarios no entra todo ésto, por límite de caracteres.